# Mockito When() is not working

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

So I break down my code a bit to make it more general and also easier for others to understand with the similar issue

this is my main code:

```
protected void methodA(String name) {
        Invocation.Builder requestBuilder = webTarget.request();
        requestBuilder.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authent.getPassword());

            response = request.invoke();

            if (response.equals("unsuccessfull")) {
                log.warn("warning blabla: {} ({})"); 
            } else {
                log.info("info blabla {}");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

while my test code looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testMethodA() throws Exception {            
    final String name = "testName";

    this.subject.methodA(name);

    Authent authent = Mockito.mock(Authent.class);

    when(authent.getPassword()).thenReturn("testPW");
    assertEquals(1, logger.infos.size());

}
```

as I said the code is more complex I broke it down and made it shorter..... hope still it is readable.

My problem is not that my `when().thenReturn()` doesn't work and therefore my code doesn't proceed further.... I guess my mocking doesn't work properly for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You test the `methodA()` method but you mock the `Authent` class and record a behavior for it after invoking the tested method :

```
this.subject.methodA(name);
Authent authent = Mockito.mock(Authent.class);
when(authent.getPassword()).thenReturn("testPW");
```

This is helpless as the method to test was already invoked.
It should be done in the reverse way :

```
Authent authent = Mockito.mock(Authent.class);
when(authent.getPassword()).thenReturn("testPW");
this.subject.methodA(name);
```

Besides, mocking an object is first step.
If the mocked object is not associated to the object under test, it will have no effect on the object under test.

You should do something in this way :

```
Authent authent = Mockito.mock(Authent.class);
// record behavior for the mock
when(authent.getPassword()).thenReturn("testPW");

// create the object under test with the mock
this.subject = new Subject(authent);

// call your method to test
this.subject.methodA(name);

// do your assertions
...
```

Comment: here aswell I get a null pointer exception because authent is "null" even though I implemented it as you did here

Comment: Are you sure that the `Subject(Authent authent);` constructor assigns the `authent` parameter to its `Authent authent` field ?

Comment: yes I have the `@Autowired Authent authent;` in the top of my main class and the constructor which has the following code `this.authent=authent;`

Comment: So you have probably the NullPointerException for another field. Ensure that this field is valued (naturally instantiated if you don't need to mock it or mocked if you need to)

Answer (score 1):

You have to mock before you invoke the method under test.
Also you have to inject that mock into your class under test.

With added structural comments this would look like:

```
@Test
public void testMethodA() throws Exception {            
    // Arrange
    final String name = "testName";
    Authent authentMock = Mockito.mock(Authent.class);
    when(authentMock.getPassword()).thenReturn("testPW");

    this.subject.setAuthent(authentMock);

    // Act
    this.subject.methodA(name);

    // Assert
    assertEquals(1, logger.infos.size());

}
```

Comment: now I get a null pointer exception because authentMock is "null" even though I implemented it as you did here

Comment: try to add the code which creates this.subject instance in your test class

Comment: okay I got the problem the other fields which I autowired in my main class seem to be null now, I guess I have to mock them aswell even though I don't want to?

Comment: if they are used in the method under test. like webTarget.. then yes you should